# How to make multiple child component and routes in angular 4

Tags: angular

i have to make one component with module like dashboard

```
dashboard.module.ts
dashboard-routing.module.ts
dashboard.component.ts
dashboard.component.html
```

and i import dashboard.module in app.module.ts, after it again  i have to make child of dashboard like department

```
department.module.ts
department-routing.module.ts
department.component.ts
department.component.html
```

and import department.module in dashboard.module.ts

i am stuck at how to make child relation in routes like
 localhost:3000/dashboard/department

without dashboard, department should not be load 
means localhost:3000/department should not work

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to add in the dashboard routing module the children array on it and it will work well like:

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, children: [
      { path: 'department', component: DepartmentComponent }
    ]
  }
]
```

**Updated:**

A stackblitz example you provide in comments with a working example on it: 
 https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-module-stack?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: ERROR in Could not resolve module ./DepartmentsModule/departments.module relative to /C/Users/Admin/Desktop/DemoRouter/rdome/src/app/dashboard/dashboard-routing.module.ts

Comment: This is the error I got, though I followed your steps. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think if you make the Dashboard as a feature module and Department as a Feature Module also, you should declare the Department Module into Dashboard Module.

Comment: After importing Department module, I got this error

Comment: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: undefined is not a function
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at webpackAsyncContext ($_lazy_route_resource lazy namespace object:15)
    at SystemJsNgModuleLoader.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.SystemJsNgModuleLoader.loadAndCompile (core.js:4982)
    at SystemJsNgModuleLoader.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.SystemJsNgModuleLoader.load (core.js:4974)

Comment: Can you provide a sample example in stackblitz to enlighten the problem ?

Comment: Thank you so much, pls find the link for the sample example ...... https://stackblitz.com/angular/rxdonyxndrk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Here you are and works well I think ... https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-module-stack?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 1):

It's just a correct use of forRoot and forChild, you can use this sample for your proper routing using childrens.

for your structure I think the best it's:

```
app /
    |-> pages
        |-> dashboard
            |-> dashboard.component.ts
            |-> dashboard.component.html
        |-> department
            |-> department.component.ts
            |-> department.component.html
        |-> pages.module.ts
        |-> pages.routes.ts  // forChild
        |-> pages.component.ts
    |-> app.module.ts
    |-> app.routes.ts  // forRoot
    |-> app.component.ts
    |-> app.component.html
    |-> app.component.css
```

and for your app.routes.ts:

```
    // forRoot
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
    { path: '' }
];

export const APP_ROUTING = RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES, { useHash: true });
```

For your pages.routes then use:

```
    //forChild

import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { PagesComponent } from './pages.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { DepartmentComponent } from './department/department.component';

const PAGES_ROUTES: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: PagesComponent,
        children: [
            { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, data: { titulo: 'Dashboard' } },
            { path: 'department', component: DepartmentComponent, data: { titulo: 'Department' } },
            { path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },

        ]
    },
];

export const PAGES_ROUTING = RouterModule.forChild(PAGES_ROUTES);
```

Hope it works for you.

Regards.
Ruslan

Comment: Thanks Ruslan, But in my case, I am creating separate routing module for each component. That is the reason I am facing problem ...

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to create routing module for app component like,

```html
const routes:Routes = [{
 { path: '',redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full'},
 { path: 'dashbord', loadChildren: app/..../dashbord.module#DashbordModule'}, 
 { path: '**', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
}]
```

Then you need to create a routing module for Dashboard component like,

```js
const routes:Route = [
{
  path:'',
  component:DashbordComponent,
  {path: '',loadChildred:'app/..../department.module#DepartmentModule'}
  }
]
```

Here

> loadChildren will lazily load your department module.

then u need to create department-routing module like below

```js
const routes:Routes = [
{
  path:'', component:DepartmentComponent , pathMatch: 'full'
}
]
```

This will load your department component.

Hopefully this will resolve your issue.

Comment: @SunandaKadam what problem are u facing?